# SWT: Layout broken when refilling a shell with components

Tags: java, swt

I want to periodically clear everything from a shell and recreate the components in it. This is a minimal Test case of what I am trying to do. At first, the labels are put side by side as the layout dictates, but when the updateThread triggers after five seconds, the newly created labels are all put over each other, completely ignoring the layout.

```
package testpkg;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell testShell = new Shell(display);
        FillLayout testLayout = new FillLayout();
        testShell.setLayout(testLayout);
        for(int i = 1; i<20; i++){
            Label label = new Label(testShell, SWT.BORDER);
            label.setText("HELLO"+i);
            label.pack();
        }
        testShell.open();
        Thread updateThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try {Thread.sleep(5000);} catch (Exception e){};
                display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        for(Control control : testShell.getChildren()){
                            control.dispose();
                        }
                        for(int i = 1; i<20; i++){
                            Label label = new Label(testShell, SWT.BORDER);
                            label.setText("HELLO"+i);
                            label.pack();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        updateThread.start();
        while (!testShell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

I want to update the (variable amount of) labels periodically but the layout breaks completely when I do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put this line after the for loop:

```
    testShell.layout(true);
```

so the final run() method will look like:

```
    public void run() {
      for (Control control : testShell.getChildren()) {
        control.dispose();
      }
      for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        Label label = new Label(testShell, SWT.BORDER);
        label.setText("HELLO"+i);
        label.pack();
      }
      testShell.layout(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that resizing the window fixed everything. So if I make the window larger and then smaller for a split second, it works.